# How to check if an expression is real in some domain

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I was wondering if it is easy to see if a given expression evaluates to a real number in a given domain? Let $f(x,y,z)$ be some function depending on three variables $x,y,z$. I would like to know if $f(x,y,z)$ is real in some domain, e.g., $x > 0, y < 0, \vert z \vert < 1$ or $x > 0, y < 0, z < g(x,y)$ (the last condition on $z$ here just means for a given $x$ and $y$, $z$ must be smaller than the value $g(x,y)$).

I've tried a few things already but it seems I can't get it to work without specifying my variables from the outset (in which case I would then see if the function was real by eye). However, for many different $(x,y,z)$-tuples this becomes tedious and I would like to see if it's possible to see if a function is real for all points in some domain within Mathematica.

Let

```
f(x,y,z) = PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z]
```

be a typical function I am dealing with.

I tried

```
Reduce[PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z] ∈ Reals && x > 0 && y < 0 && z < 1]
```

but this system cannot be solved by `Reduce`. I've also tried

```
FunctionDomain[PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z], {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

but it did not help either. I am using version 11.1.1.

Comment: You can try `FunctionDomain` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you. I have tried this and I get the error 'Unable to find the domain with the available methods'. It seems this function `FunctionDomain` cannot cope with the PolyLog[2,x], which is part of my f(x,y,z).

Comment: With version 12.1.1 `FunctionDomain[PolyLog[2, x], x]` evaluates to `x <= 1`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, I see, I am unfortunately using version 11.1.1

Comment: First, `FunctionDomain[PolyLog[2, x], x, Reals]` performs `x<1` in version 12.0. Second, this is an empty talk without knowing your `f(x,y,z)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just get an overview with `RegionPlot3D` .

```
RegionPlot3D[
    PolyLog[2, x*y/z] - PolyLog[2, -x*y/z] \[Element] Reals && x > 0 && 
      y < 0 && z < 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]